# check where a list entry is not 0.0

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

How to check is a List entry is not e.g. 0.0?

I just know how to check if it is 0.0 like this:

```
MyList.Where(a => a.Equals(0.0))
```

but how to check it if it's not?

Comment: `a => a != 0.0`?
€: What type of List<T> are we talking here?

Comment: Apart from the linq context, how would you normally check if anything is unequal in C#? What problems did you have to transfer that knowledge to Linq?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if a list contains a number: `if (myList.Contains(0.0)) ...`

To check if a list does NOT contain a number: `if (!myList.Contains(0.0)) ...`